# Error in parallel calculation on R function

Tags: r, parallel-processing, doparallel, fitdistrplus, rparallel

I am mastering parallel programming in R simple examples tried to implement the function given in the code, it loads the processor, but the results of calculations are not. Could you please tell me where I made a mistake in the code?

```
library(foreach)
library(doSNOW)

power_Ks_Cauchy_par <- function(resp, alpha, distData, sample)
{
       corNum<-detectCores()-1
       cluster <- makeCluster(corNum, type = "SOCK", outfile="")
       registerDoSNOW(cluster)
       power <- c()
       num <- c()
         foreach(i=3:sample, .combine=rbind) %dopar%{
            distPar <- fitdistrplus::fitdist(data = distData[1:i],"cauchy")
            loc <- distPar$estimate[1]
            sc <- distPar$estimate[2] 
            test<-mean(replicate(resp,(ks.test(rcauchy(i, loc, sc),"pnorm")$`p.value`<alpha)))
            power<-c(power,test)
            num <- c(num,i)
          }
        power <- data.frame(power, samples=num)
        stopCluster(cluster)
        return(power)
}

     repl<-10000
     alpha <- 0.05
     samles <- length(baseDataMeh$Sigma02)
     time1<-system.time({
     resKStestCauchy_1 <- power_Ks_Cauchy_par(repl,alpha = alpha,    
     distData=baseDataMeh$Sigma02,sample=samles)
     })
```

I tried several variants of paralleling, but on my architecture only implementation through these libraries  gave a gain in calculation time on simple examples.

The code implemented through for in a function works, but it takes a very long time to calculate.

The function loads the processor, but there is no calculation result at the output.

Could you please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider directly assigning an object to `foreach` call. If using `.combine`, `foreach` resembles an apply family function (i.e., lapply, sapply) to return an object (equal length to iterable) and not simply `for` loop to iteratively update environment objects.

Below adjustment returns *test* in `foreach` function and assigns to *power_vec* object. Also, `num` capturing i-th number is not needed.

```r
power_vec <- foreach(
  i=3:sample, .combine=rbind
) %dopar% {
  distPar <- fitdistrplus::fitdist(data = distData[1:i],"cauchy")
  loc <- distPar$estimate[1]
  sc <- distPar$estimate[2] 
  test <- mean(
    replicate(
      resp, (ks.test(rcauchy(i, loc, sc),"pnorm")$`p.value`<alpha)
    )
  )
}

power_df <- data.frame(power=power_vec, samples=3:sample)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. This is indeed a good option, it became much faster to count. Now it is much clearer.